# Make a div non-responsive within a responsive based template?

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a simple template that is responsive.  I have a form that is already formatted to be narrow and I don't want the div in which the form sits to be responsive within the RWD based template.  What CSS attribute(s) would I use to make a div non-responsive?  In other words, in general, the page is responsive but in this one area I'd like the containing div to not be responsive and to keep its width.  The div in question contains a CSS based table-less scenario where a child div sits to the left and contains a field name and another div sits to the right containing a form element.  Therefore I'd like the form to not respond and just sit there.  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your scenario without any code, but try explicitly setting a width to your container div.

```
#container {
   width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bryant. Yes it is exactly that easy.  For whatever reason when I tried this width setting on the encapsulating div yesterday it was not working. I can only speculate that it was because my ending divs were messed up.

Comment: Awesome! If you don't mind, you can mark my answer as the accepted answer and I get imaginary internet points.